# post json array to POST api in angular2

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I've an POST api `http://localhost:5000/cities` that accepts the following sample json as payload.

```
[{ "id": 1, "name": "LA", "number": 2, "country": "US"}]
```

I've a service.ts file

```
cities(city_id, city_name, city_number, city_country): Observable<Result> {
return this.post(this.getURL(), city_id, city_name, city_number, city_country);
}
```

In my component ts file, I'm calling the service to pass the data

```
function () {
    self.CityService.cities(id, name, number, country).subscribe(
      response => {
        swal({
          title: "",
          text: "",
          type: "success",
          timer: 1500,
          showConfirmButton: false
        });
```

How do I convert the parameters into json array `[{ "id": 1, "name": "LA", "number": 2, "country": "US"}]`  to post to the api?

Comment: It seems redundant to send the properties individually only to be merged(?) again in the POST request. How does the actual payload look in the POST request?

Comment: @Michael `[{ "id": 1, "name": "LA", "number": 2, "country": "US"}]`. This kinda payload is accepted to the post api. I dont know how to convert the parameters into json array

Comment: Apologies I misunderstood the question. You could send the array instead of individual arguments in the call: `self.CityService.cities([{id, name, number, country}])` and use it as the payload: `cities(body: any) { return this.http.post(this.getUrl(), body); }`

Comment: does angular convert the data in array as key-value pair? for example
id:1 , name: "LA", number: 2, "country": "LA"

Comment: Angular is only a framework based on Typescript (+HTML+Style). Typescript is a superset of Javascript. And in Javascript when the variables `id`, `name`, `number`, and `country` are defined, the construct `[{id, name, number, country}]` will produce `[{ "id": 1, "name": "LA", "number": 2, "country": "US"}]`. See this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/38wombzy/

Comment: @MichaelD Thanks for your explanation and I accept your answer.